# Adding data frame to excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write a dataframe to excel using `panda.ExcelWriter` after reading it from a huge csv file.

This code updates the excel sheet but it doesn't appends the data to the excel which I want

```
import pandas as pd 

reader = pd.read_csv("H:/ram/temp/1.csv", delimiter = '\t' ,chunksize = 10000, names = ['neo_user_id', 
    'gender',
    'age_range',
    'main_geolocation', # (user identifier of the client)
    'interest_category_1',
    'interest_category_2',
    'interest_category_3',
    'first_day_identifier'
    ],  encoding="utf-8")

ew = pd.ExcelWriter('H:/ram/Formatted/SynthExport.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})
for chunks in reader:
    chunks.to_excel(ew, 'Sheet1' , encoding = 'utf-8')
    print len(chunks)
ew.save()
```

I also tried to use `data.append()` and `data.to_excel` doing this result is memory error. Since I am reading data in chunks is there any way to write the data to excel

I got it working by this code

```
import pandas as pd 
import xlsxwriter
reader = pd.read_csv("H:/ram/user_action_export.2014.01.csv", delimiter = '\t', chunksize = 1000, names = ['day_identifier', 
    'user_id',
    'site_id',
    'device', # (user identifier of the client)
    'geolocation',
    'referrer',
    'pageviews',
    ],  encoding="utf-8")

startrows = 0
ew = pd.ExcelWriter('H:/ram/Formatted/ActionExport.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', options={'encoding':'utf-8'})

for chunks in reader:
    chunks.to_excel(ew, 'Sheet1' , encoding = 'utf-8', startrow = startrows)
    startrows = startrows + len(chunks)
    print startrows 

ew.save()
```

But still take so much time

Comment: The excel writers take a start row argument. You can track the length of your chunks and use that to find the next empty row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is causing the main issue but you shouldn't be calling `save()` between chunks since a single call to `save()` closes an `xlsxwriter` file.

Comment: There were 9182321 rows in that csv and it took 8270.3s to get it completed, is there any faster way to do it also since the maximum number of rows in excel is 1048576 the whole data didn't get copied. Where to save it ?

Comment: 9 million rows x N columns is a lot of data and XLSX is not a simple file format. On a medium machine you can expect about 20 sec per million cells with XlsxWriter. With [constant_memory](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_memory.html) mode in XlsxWriter it may be a little faster (15 sec per million cells) and it won't consume all the memory on your system. You will need to use that outside of Pandas however.

Comment: My system configuration is 4 GB Ram 640 GB HardDisk i5 Processor Widows8 1.7 Ghz and I am trying to write an excel file that is present in an external Hard Disk